# How to sort array by date In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem to sort arrays that are in an array object by date.

I have an array object as below.

```
[
  {
    "name": "February",
    "plantingDate": "2018-02-04T17:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "name": "March",
    "plantingDate": "2018-03-04T17:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "name": "January",
    "plantingDate": "2018-01-17T17:00:00.000Z",
  }
]
```

How to sort the array in the array object from January to December, as below.

```
[
  {
    "name": "January",
    "plantingDate": "2018-01-17T17:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "name": "February",
    "plantingDate": "2018-02-04T17:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "name": "March",
    "plantingDate": "2018-03-04T17:00:00.000Z",
  }
]
```

I beg for help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: i think it similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Parse strings to get Date objects, then [sort by compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
var a = [
  {
    "name": "February",
    "plantingDate": "2018-02-04T17:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "name": "March",
    "plantingDate": "2018-03-04T17:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "name": "January",
    "plantingDate": "2018-01-17T17:00:00.000Z",
  }
]

a.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(a.plantingDate) - new Date(b.plantingDate)
})

console.log(a)
```

As Barmar [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287060/how-to-sort-array-by-date-in-javascript/52287096?noredirect=1#comment91522028_52287096),

```
a.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.plantingDate.localeCompare(b.plantingDate);
})
```

will also work.

Comment: The comparison function is supposed to return a number, not a boolean. The sign of the number is used to determine the ordering.

Comment: I have tried to do it, but the month is sorted. How can the dates in the month be sorted sir.

Comment: *localeCompare* is better. a.dateValue - b.dateValue might work okay with JS. It does *not* work with TypeScript - wont' compile because of date type. TypeScript expects numeric values including enum.